# How to break up data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, parameters

I have this data frame and i stuck trying to split them into other datasets based on year. Like "2020, 2021"

For example:
"2020"
ALL 2020 Year Values

"2021"
ALL 2021 Year Values
I named it: Dataset

```
Date    Left    Right   Up  Down  Middle  Size
1/1/2020    1   1   2   2   2   2
2/1/2020    1   7   8   9   8   8
3/1/2020    2   3   4   6   7   8
1/1/2021    1   2   2   2   2   7
2/1/2021    1   7   8   9   8   8
3/1/2021    2   3   4   6   7   8
```

Im still very new at R and just having issues culling down data
If anyone could help, im forgive grateful

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. To help us help you please include the code you have tried in the question. You may find it helpful to look at the this link [MRE]. Please add your data in a dataframe format e.g. df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data! And if applicable explain what you have tried out prior to asking your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract year from date and then use `split` to get list of dataframes for each year.

```
output <- split(df, format(as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y"))
output
#$`2020`
#      Date Left Right Up Down Middle Size
#1 1/1/2020    1     1  2    2      2    2
#2 2/1/2020    1     7  8    9      8    8
#3 3/1/2020    2     3  4    6      7    8

#$`2021`
#      Date Left Right Up Down Middle Size
#4 1/1/2021    1     2  2    2      2    7
#5 2/1/2021    1     7  8    9      8    8
#6 3/1/2021    2     3  4    6      7    8
```

You can also achieve that using `lubridate` functions.

```
library(lubridate)
output <- split(df, year(dmy(df$Date)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", "1/1/2021", 
"2/1/2021", "3/1/2021"), Left = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Right = c(1L, 
7L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 3L), Up = c(2L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 4L), Down = c(2L, 
9L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 6L), Middle = c(2L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 7L), Size = c(2L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Note that the date format may also use `'%m/%d/%Y'` (or `mdy(...)` for `lubridate`) if the dates are US style with the month first.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Although there is not enough information to say that for sure.

Comment: I agree. Which is why I added a comment to note both options, on an answer that assumes one of them.